# C# How to init property (without setter) by reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, protocol-buffers

**Task:**
Serialize a list of objects into a byte[] using protobuf.

Without reflection all is good

.proto

```
message MyObject{
  int32 id = 1;
  int32 value = 2;
}

message MyObjects {
  repeated MyObject objects = 1;
}
```

.cs

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray(List<MyObject> obj) {
    var objects = new MyObjects {
        Objects = {obj}
    };
    return objects.ToByteArray();
}
```

Since I need to serialize many different types in this way, I want to write a universal method using reflection.

**Problem:**
Protobuf itself generates entities and properties for them, but it does not create a setter for RepeatedField, which means that I can not set the value using `GetProperty("Objects")?.SetValue(objects, obj)`. *System.ArgumentException: Set Method not found for 'Objects'*

.cs (protobuf generated)

```
public pbc::RepeatedField<global::Test.MyObject> Objects {
  get { return objects_; }
}
```

.cs

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray<T, E>(List<T> obj) where T : IMessage where E : IMessage {
    var objects = Activator.CreateInstance<E>();
    objects.GetType().GetProperty("Objects")?.SetValue(objects, obj);
    return objects.ToByteArray();
}
```

**Question:**
How to use reflection to set values ​​for a property during object creation, just as I do it without reflection?

How to write this "`new MyObjects {Objects = {obj}};` (where obj: IEnumerable)" using reflection

**Various conclusions:**

- I noticed that filling properties that do not have a setter is only possible for collections and only when creating an object.
- Most likely I need an alternative way to instantiate the class. Activator.CreateInstance() is not fulfilling my task.

Comment: Removed protobuf-net because this is Google.protobuf, not protobuf-net; however, it is pretty normal to have non-settable collections. Just clear and add what you need.

Comment: A property is syntactic sugar for two methods (the setter and the getter). These are actual c# methods that are hidden from you but in all other respects are the same as a "normal" method. A read-only property has only one method (the getter). In this case you cannot call the setter because it doesn't exist. The only thing you can do is write code that does what a setter *would* do if it existed, e.g. try to set a private backing field. This isn't recommended; the name of the backing field is an implementation detail that you shouldn't depend on. Also, not all properties have a backing field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we do this:

```
var x = new Thing
{
    SomeProperty = "x",
    SomeOtherProperty = 1
}
```

we aren't setting the values during object creation. This is the equivalent of:

```
var x = new Thing();
x.SomeProperty = "x";
x.SomeOtherProperty = 1;
```

In both cases the properties are set *after* the object is instantiated by setting their properties. An easy way to verify this is to try using the syntax from the first example to set a property that doesn't have a setter. It won't compile. You'll see this error:

> Property or indexer 'Thing.SomeProperty' cannot be assigned to -- it is read-only.

In other words, the object, as defined, does not provide a way to set the `Objects` property.

The question is whether you really need to set the property. Quite likely you only need to add items to the collection.

Doing this with reflection is still really ugly. I don't recommend this at all. This is a crude version. It can fail at runtime for all sorts of reasons.

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray<T, E>(List<T> itemsToAdd) where T : IMessage where E : IMessage
{
    // create an instance of the object
    var created = Activator.CreateInstance<E>();

    // Find the "Objects" property. It could be null. It could be the wrong type.
    var objectsProperty = typeof(E).GetProperty("Objects"); 

    // Get the value of the objects property. Hopefully it's the type you expect it to be.
    var collection = objectsProperty.GetValue(created);

    // Get the Add method. This might also be null if the method doesn't exist.
    var addMethod = collection.GetType().GetMethod("Add");

    // invoke the Add method for each item in the collection
    foreach(var itemToAdd in itemsToAdd)
    {
        addMethod.Invoke(collection, new object[] { itemToAdd });
    }
    return created.ToByteArray();
}
```

Unless we're forced to, we really don't want to do that. I don't know what your `IMessage` type look like.

Does it have the `Objects` property?

In that case you could just do this:

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray<T, E>(List<T> itemsToAdd) 
    where T : IMessage 
    where E : IMessage, new()
{
    var created = new E();
    foreach (var itemToAdd in itemsToAdd)
    {
        created.Objects.Add(itemToAdd);
    }

    // or skip the foreach and just do
    // created.Objects.AddRange(itemToAdd);

    return created.ToByteArray();
}
```

I'm guessing about whether your interface has that property. But if at all possible, you're better off doing this with generic constraints than with reflection. This way your code is checked for most possible errors when it compiles, as opposed to running it and having it blow up because this or that property or method doesn't exist, is wrong, etc.

The `new()` constraint simply means that `E` must be a type with a default constructor, which means that in order for it to compile, `E` must be a type you can create without passing anything to the constructor. (Without that constraint, `new E()` won't compile.)

Without that constraint even `Activator.CreateInstance` might fail because the the type might not have a default constructor.

Comment: I managed to solve this problem in a similar way, but I probably like yours more. I got the property value and cast it to RepeatedField <T>, and then called AddRange (obj)

Comment: The idea is that if you're looking for a certain property value that you expect to be there, it implies that you already know what the type is. That's exactly what generic constraints are for. If you don't know what the type is but you know it implements an interface that will have certain properties, then you can just specify that interface in your generic constraint.

Comment: I did not know that protobuf has a concept of interfaces. I will read the documentation. Thank you very much for the decision.

Answer (score 0):

[Scott's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5101046/scott-hannen) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62544807/10027257) solves the problem, but I used a shortened solution in the end

```
    private static byte[] ToByteArray<T, E>(IEnumerable<T> obj) where T : IMessage where E : IMessage, new() {
        var objects = new E();
        (objects.GetType().GetProperty("Objects")?.GetValue(objects) as RepeatedField<T>)?.AddRange(obj);
        return objects.ToByteArray();
    }
```